# Avoiding ORA-00054 when altering column to not null

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I would like to avoid the following or any other error message when altering an existing column to "not null" on a heavy used table:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
00054. 00000 -  "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired"
*Cause:    Interested resource is busy.
*Action:   Retry if necessary or increase timeout.
```

My Oracle version is: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production. I tried it with an exclusive lock as follows, but I still get the error. I simulated a heavy used table by do some DML in other sessions.

Session 1

```
create table iei1731 (
  col1 varchar2(1 char),
  col2 number(1,0)
);
insert into iei1731 (col1, col2) values ('1', 0);
commit;
update iei1731 set col1 = col1 where col1 = '1';
```

Session 2

```
lock table iei1731 in exclusive mode;
```

Session 1

```
rollback; -- now session 2 gets the exclusive lock on the table
update iei1731 set col1 = col1 where col1 = '1';
```

Session 2

```
alter table iei1731 modify col2 not null; -- here I get the ORA-00054
```

Session 1 (cleanup)

```
rollback;
drop table iei1731;
```

So my question is if there exist any possibility to set the column on this heavy used table to not null without any error message?

Comment: Maybe this is a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams074.htm#REFRN10267) to have the session wait for the lock:

```
--Wait up to 10 minutes to acquire the lock.
alter session set DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT=600;
alter table iei1731 modify col2 not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is locked exclusively - NO - the lock will have to released first.

Also making a not null change is a metadata change, so you will create a possible 'row cache' lock if this object is heavily accessed, and that row cache lock will make others wait in the queue for object access until your not null is successful.  This can cause a nasty snowball of waits in a busy production environment.  It is better to make metadata changes during downtime or less busy times.

Comment: But it is session 2 which holds the exclusive lock. And session 2 will then set the column to not null and gets the error. Also when I remove the exclusive lock statement, I get the ORA-00054.